# An inequality related to a semigroup of operators.

Tags: integration, inequality, semigroup-of-operators

I would like to prove that
$$4CLh\int_0^t {\frac{{ds}}{{\left( {t - s + h} \right){{\left( {t - s} \right)}^{1 - \theta }}}}}  \leq {C_1}{h^\theta }$$

where $\theta  \in \left( {0,1} \right)$. $C, L, C_1 ,h$ are constants greater than $0$.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to explain where this question comes from? It would be helpful to understand the motivation, particularly with regards to how the question relates to the title. Also, could you share any research you've done already on this question?

Comment: I encountered this problem in learning the theory of operator semigroups, this integral is apparently convergent, this is because put t-s+h into h easy to get,how to prove this inequality?

Comment: @Ltaian You can take substitution such as $(t-s)/h = x$.

Comment: You are right, thank you very much.